# Symfony link/route working on Linux brower but not on Windows browser

Tags: php, linux, windows, symfony

Has anyone ever had the problem that a link in the application is perfectly working on Linux browsers but not on Windows browsers?

I have a modal, that has two buttons, one is leading to another page, the other one is just closing the modal. In my Linux environment in Chromium the button for the new route is working but when trying to do the same thing on Windows (in either Internet Explorer or Firefox) it's not working. Nothing happens when clicking the button. Closing the modal on the other hand is working fine.

Any ideas on this issue?

**Update**

```
  {% if not item.archived %}
    <a href= "#archiveModal{{ item.id }}" data-toggle="modal" class="fa fa-folder" data-placement="top" title="Archive"></i></a>
    <div id="archiveModal{{ item.id }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure?</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Do you really want to archive this document?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">
              Go Back
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-warning">
              <a href="{{ path('documentBundle_document_archive', {'id':item.id}) }}" style="color: #FEFEFE">Yes</a>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
   ...
    {% endif %}
```

The problem occurs with the "Yes" Button (path 'documentBundle_document_archive) There is no JavaScript for this modal, so unfortunately I can't provide any.

Here's the action for the path:

```
  /**
* @Route("/document/{id}/archive", name="documentBundle_document_archive" , requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 0})
* @Method("GET")
* @Template()
*/
public function archiveAction(Request $request, $id) {

        /*
         * CHECK FOR PERMISSIONS
         * TODO: Check if the acting user has all needed permissions to perform this action.
         */
         if($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_DOCUMENT_EDIT')){


                /*
                 * GET DOCUMENT FROM DB
                 */
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $updated_document = $em->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Document')->find($id);

                /*
                 * IF DOCUMENT IS NOT ARCHIVED
                 */
                if(!$updated_document->isArchived())
                {

        // TODO: Send email with activation link to verify the user's email address! TODO: Create Event

                        /*
                         * GET CURRENT USER
                         */
                        $currentuser = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

                        /*
                         * ARCHIVE DOCUMENT
                         */
                        $updated_document->setArchived(true);

                        /*
                         * ADD AN APPROVAL COMMENT
                         */
                        $comment = new \CommentBundle\Entity\Comment();
                        $comment->setComment('<strong>Document was archived.</strong>');
                        $comment->setDocument($updated_document);
                        $comment->setAuthor($currentuser);

                        /*
                         * PERSIST DATA
                         */
                        $em->persist($updated_document);
                        $em->persist($comment);
                        $em->flush();

                        /*
                         * DISPLAY SUCCESS MESSAGE
                         */
                         $this->addFlash(
                         'success',
                         'The document has been archived!'
                         );
                      return $this->redirectToRoute('documentBundle_document_list');

                } else {
                        /*
                         * DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE
                         */
                        return $this->render('DocumentBundle:Action/Document:archived.html.twig', Array(
                                'success' => false,
                                'updated_document' => $updated_document,
                                'menu' => Array('top' => 'Document'),
                        ));
                }

        } else
        {
                /*
                 * THROW ERROR
                 * If the acting user is not allowed to perform this action
                 */
                return $this->get('app.error_helper')->throwPermissionError();
        }
}
```

Comment: This is way too vague. Readers expect some copy/pasteable code that will illustrate the problem.  Please read about [Minimal,Complete,Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your Q. Good luck.

Comment: It seems like you're talking about the frontend, in which case it might be a JavaScript issue - perhaps it is sensitive to the host OS because there's a server-side issue such as the modal downloading material via AJAX. Can you prepare a JS Fiddle for us?

Comment: Post your twig with those buttons

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers! I updated the question and provided the code for the modal! I hope this helps! :)

Comment: That's a button with an embedded `<a>` link. Should it not be one or the other? Are you expecting a click to follow a link or submit a form?

Comment: it should submit something. So when "Yes" is clicked, the document is archived . I added the function from the Controller for that path :)

Comment: @halfer

sorry to disturb you again but after 2 days of googling I'm still struggling with the issue.. did the code above help you a little bit?
It's really super weird because all of my routes/links are working on windows and linux but only the one described above for archiving a document seems not to be working.
creating a jsFiddle didn't work because I would need the whole controller action as well as the twig file and database entries, right? but maybe you still have any ideas or I can provide you with some more code/infos?

Comment: I haven't been looking at this, as I didn't see your reply yesterday (you need to use `@halfer` every time to ping me, unless I am the only commenter). I still think a button with a link in it is an invalid construction, and I think that needs to be addressed directly. (1) Are you sure that is valid?

Comment: (2) Since submission needs a form, do you have one? You have not shown one in your question. (3) You've shown us some PHP, but are you sure a form submission is occurring at all? If it is not then the server side will not be called. (4) Since Bootstrap uses JavaScript, this could still be a JS issue. Open your JS console in your browser and see if there are any error reports in there.

Comment: If you could reply on all four of my enumerated points, that would be helpful.

Comment: @halfer thank you!
(1) yes I think that is valid since it is working.. only for that sepcific  path on windows it does not :/
(2) you are right! basically I have a list of documents (see twig file) and then when archiving something (submitting) the page is reloaded, showing a success message (see controller)
(3) I am sure that everything is working since it is perfectly working on linux. if it wasn't valid, it wouldn't work on both, linux and windows, right? but it's only not working on windows and also only for that one specific route
(4) I had a look at the console but there was nothing.

Comment: OK, thanks. I infer from your question that "not working on Windows" refers to the browser, not the web server. Is that right? I wonder, could you deploy a demo application to the web, in case that helps see what is wrong?

Comment: ehm I don't know whether I understood it correctly: it's not working on the operating system Windows (neither in Internet Explorer, nor in Firefox) but on Linux (web browser = chromium). I guess I'm not advanced enough to deploy something like that.. I would assume that there is some setting that restricts my path from being used in windows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155015/discussion-between-halfer-and-sonja).